# When append the javascript in html using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({   
                 url: "sub_template5_js.php?content_id="+content_id,  
                 dataType: 'html',
                 success: function(data){  
                    data = data.replace( new RegExp("block1", 'g'), block_id_replace );
                     data = data.replace( new RegExp("<//script>", 'g'), '' );
                    data = data.replace( new RegExp("<script>", 'g'), '' );
                    alert(data);
                    $("#template_ipad script").empty;
                    $("#template_ipad script").append(data);
                }    
         });
```

Above script when i alert the data it's showing some thing like this

```
imagePath=$prev.find('img').map(function(){
                                    return this.src.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
                                    }).get();
        imagePath = "images/"+imagePath;
```

after append

```
imagePath=$prev.find('img').map(function(){
                                    return this.src.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
                                    }).get();
        imagePath = "images/" imagePath;
```

u can see above code after append **'+'** is missing plz help me

**Before **

imagePath = "images/"+imagePath;

**After **

imagePath = "images/" imagePath;

Thank You

Comment: If you're using AJAX to load some script and run it (as it looks to be what you're trying to do here), you might have better mileage doing that via `$.getScript()` instead.

Comment: The argument to `append()` is supposed to be a string of HTML.

Comment: The .text() function is generally used to set element content without any encoding.  Although this will obviously replace the entire contents rather than just append some data but this would remove the need for the .empty() call in the example.